# Test IE7 without installing it - how?

Tags: debug, internet-explorer-7

Is there a way to test IE7 functionality (intented to test the functionality of a website) without installing IE7?

If so, how?

Something like an online service?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IF you have IE8 or IE9 installed in your PC:

- press <kbd>F12</kbd> for the developer window
- on the Menu, click browser mode and select IE7.

The Currently active browser tab is now in IE7 mode.

[image]

Comment: This approach often fails to recognize bugs that break IE7.

Answer (score 3):

you should try MS Virtual Labs,

MSDN Virtual Labs : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa570323.aspx

Technet Virtual Labs : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/virtuallabs

I think that Windows Vista comes with IE7 default, Vista Lab : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/virtuallabs/bb539979

Comment: we use Windows XP, thx for your answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Browserling](http://browserling.com/), which has a nice selection of browsers to choose from.

Comment: thx for your answer, browserling looks nice